# Deficient Tutte's Theorem

Tags: graph-theory

Everyone knows the Tutte's Theorem (necessary & sufficient condition for a graph to have a perfect matching - viz [wikipedia page on Tutte's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_theorem)).

The deficient version of this Theorem is:

> G has matching covering all vertices with exception of at most *k* vertices
>
> iff
>
> for any subset S of V(G) holds that the number of odd components of G-S is at most *|S|+k*

Obviously, Tutte's Theorem is special case of deficient Tutte's Theorem for *k* equal to zero.

Can this version be somehow be easily proven with aid of the original Tutte's Theorem? E.g. with transformation of G to some more convenient graph, where Tutte's condition would hold...

Comment: It's not true that everyone knows the theorem. I do not! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Posting this here in case someone needs it later (as I couldn't find this theorem anywhere).

---

$G$ has a matching covering $2n$ vertices excluding $k$ vertices $\implies$ for any $S \subseteq V(G)$, one has $o(G-S) \leq |S| + k$.

WLOG, write $|G| = 2n+ k$. Construct $H$ by adding $k$ more vertices to $G$ such that $|H| = 2(n+k)$ with the property that each vertex added is connected to every vertex in $G$. That is, $H$ is the graph,
$$
V(H) = V(G) \cup \{v_1, \cdots, v_k\}, \qquad E(H)= E(V) \cup \bigcup_{i=1}^k \{v_1 u \mid \forall u \in V(G)\}.
$$

Clearly, if $G$ has an $n$ matching, $H$ has a $n+k$ matching. By Tutte's theorem, for any subset $S_H \subseteq V(H)$, $o(H - S_H) \leq |S_H|$. Let $S_G \subseteq V(G)$ be some arbitary subset. Consider $S_H = S_G \cup \{v_1, \cdots, v_k\} \subseteq V(H)$, $|S_H| = |S_G| + k$. Now note that $H - S_H \cong G - S_G$. So $o(H-S_H) = o(G - S_G)$. We hence have,
$$
o(G-S_G) = o(H - S_H) \leq |S_H| = |S_G |+k.
$$
So we have proven that for any subset $S_G \subseteq V(G)$, $o(G-S_G) = |S_G| + k$, if $G$ has a $2n$ matching.

---

For any $S \subseteq V(G)$, $o(G-S) \leq |S| + k$ $\implies$ $G$ has a matching covering $2n$ vertices excluding $k$ vertices .

Our strategy here is to construct $H$ as above, show that $H$ has a $n+k$ matching, and remove $\{v_1, \cdots, v_k\}$ to give $G$ a $n$ matching. A small issue comes up that we do not know that $|G| - k$ is even yet, but that will be fixed.

Construct $H$ as above.
$$
V(H) = V(G) \cup \{v_1, \cdots, v_k\}, \qquad E(H)= E(V) \cup \bigcup_{i=1}^k \{v_1 u \mid \forall u \in V(G)\}.
$$
Let $S_H \subseteq V(H)$ be an arbitrary subset of vertices of $H$. If $ \exists \ v_i \in V(H)$, $1 \leq i \leq n$, such that $v_i \notin S_H$, then $H$ is connected. Then $o(H - S_H) \leq 1 \leq |S_H|$. If $\{v_1, \cdots, v_k\} \in S_H$, consider $S_G \subseteq V(G)$ such that $S_G = S_H \setminus \{v_1, \cdots, v_k\}$. Note $H - S_H \cong G - S_G$. Hence $o(H - S_H) = o(G - S_G) \leq |S_G| + k = |S_H|$. By Tutte's theroem, $H$ has a complete matching. (This implies $|H|$ is even, which means $|G| + k$ is even, so $|G| - k$ is even, allowing us to say that $G$ has a matching that excludes $k$ vertices.)

Since $H$ has a complete matching, removing $\{v_1, \cdots, v_k\}$ gives back $G$ with a matching that leaves out $k$ vertices.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the proof might work like this:

Let C be a complete graph of k vertices, we make a new graph C+G where we connect every vertice of C with every vertice of G.

Lets examine the Tutte condition in this graph.

- If C is not a subset of S, the number of odd components is at most 1 because the part of C that is not in S connects all of the components in G together.
- Otherwise the number of odd components can be at most |S intersection G|+k, but thats exactly how big S is.

Now that the Tutte condition works, we get a perfect matching. If you remove C from the matching the resulting matching will cover the vertices of G except at most k vertices.

Comment: As pointed out there is a problem with the parity of G+C, if you add a correct complete graph, this method still works. But now im pretty sure there is a nicer way to do this.
Adding a k-1 vertice complete graph for the case where the parity of k and |G| differs will fix this problem though. If k is odd and |G| even, you will never need more than k-1 unpaired vertices and same thing if k is even and |G| odd.